# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, template-inheritance

I can't get rid of this exception and I have no idea what's wrong. Thanks for everything.

This is my python file

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")
```

And this is my login.html

```
{% extends = "layout.html" %}


{% block title %}
    Login
{% endblock %}

{% block heading %}Login {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Login</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{% block heading %} {% endblock %}</h1>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not nest blocks like that.

Comment: I changed it, so that I don't nest them, but it still doesn't work, I'll edit the code on here, so that it looks like mine.

Comment: Now it's edited. But it still doesn't work

Comment: @OliverHnát do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **[Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures)** documentation, you cannot put **equal to (=)** for statements like **{% extends %}** in your template.

Your **login.html** should be like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    Login
{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}Login {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Login</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

for more info [Check this.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `{% extends "layout.html" %}` instead of `{% extends = "layout.html" %}`.

If it doesn't work, you can also try taking out all {% %} tags and adding them back in one by one.